# Need help to store variant data in shopify using "Shopify API Node.js"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify

Hi recently I am working with reactjs & nodejs project and developing a new dashboard module like this.

[ERROR SCREEN-SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jszKq.png)

now i want to add a product to Shopify but i will send data using API for variant but by default, it saves default Shopify data like this.

[enter image description here][2]

And here is my code

1. Main Function On Submit click

   ```
   const productAddEditSubmit = () => {

    var productObject = {
        name: fullProductData.name,
        description: fullProductData.description,
        category_id: fullProductData.category_id,
        certification_type_id: fullProductData.certification_type_id,
        artwork_origin_id: fullProductData.artwork_origin_id,
        price: fullProductData.price,
        currency: fullProductData.currency,
        quantity: fullProductData.quantity,
        sku: fullProductData.sku,
        status: fullProductData.status,
        purchase_url: fullProductData.purchase_url,
        // user_id: user._id,
        update_date: new Date(),
    }

    if (productActionValue.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
        // dispatch(updateProduct(fullProductData._id, productObject, tempMediaList))
    }
    else {
        dispatch(addProductData(productObject));
    }
    }
   ```
2. Action File

   ```
    export const addProductData = (product) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/shopifyProduct', product).then((res) => {
    dispatch({
        type: ADD_PRODUCT,
        payload: res.data
    })
    })
    }
   ```

[Final Data Sent to Shopify DB Using shopify-api-node *NPM Package*][5]

3. Post Route

   ```
    router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    const getProductDataFromFrontEndPartOne = {
    title: req.body.name,
    body_html: req.body.description,
    product_type: req.body.category_id,
    status: "draft"
    }

    // getProductDataFromFrontEndPartOne this object data store in shopify
    shopify.product.create(getProductDataFromFrontEndPartOne)
    .then((res) => {

    // after res i did not store this object (getProductDataFromFrontEndPartTwo) into shopify.

        const getProductDataFromFrontEndPartTwo = {
            id: res.id,
            price: req.body.price,
            sku: req.body.sku,
            inventory_quantity: req.body.quantity
        }
        shopify.productVariant.create(getProductDataFromFrontEndPartTwo)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
    });
   ```

*Shopify.product.create* using this function to save data in Shopify if res is successful after I did send variant data into their particular product using res.id.

Comment: Can you please post the code as a code block in the post instead of a linked screenshot? Thanks!

Comment: @lxg Ok sure, I will update code block.

Comment: I don't know if it's me, but I don't see the pictures, without them is not clear what the problem is

Comment: Hi @FabioFilippi I did update the error screenshot can check, the problem is simple when I POST *getProductDataFromFrontEndPartOne * object in Shopify it will be stored in DB but at the same time After getting their response it shows an error but data already in response